# voice is not playing in sound playing android program

Tags: android, audio, voice, playing

in this program we can play 15 mp3 files with buttons.
i simulate the program in "youwave for android" and its works good.
when i test it in lenovo ideatab a3000 tablet and xperia z1 phone somtimes when we switch from one button to another it doesn't play sound and it wont play if we push the button again.
and we should push other buttons and get back to the button that didn't play sound to play sound.
and i checked programming of those buttons.
and there is another problem that sometimes when i exit the program the sound wont stop playing . 
and i added delays recently and it was not diffident before that.

and this is the program :

```
    package fifa1.com.w3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;




public class Fifa1Activity2 extends Activity {


    Button      btn0;
    Button      btn1;
    Button      btn2;
    Button      btn3;
    Button      btn4;
    Button      btn5;
    Button      btn6;
    Button      btn7;
    Button      btn8;
    Button      btn9;
    Button      btn10;
    Button      btn11;
    Button      btn12;
    Button      btn13;
    Button      btn14;
    Button      btn15;
    Button      btn16;
    Button      btn17;


    ImageView   imageView1;


    MediaPlayer md = new MediaPlayer();




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);


        btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btn10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn10);
        btn11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn11);
        btn12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn12);
        btn13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn13);
        btn14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn14);
        btn15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn15);
        btn16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn16);
        btn17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn17);


        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        btn0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2000);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2000);
                md.start();


            }
        });


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2001);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2001);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2002);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2002);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2003);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2003);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2004);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2004);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2005);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2005);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2006);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2006);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2007);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2007);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2008);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2008);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2009);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2009);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2010);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2010);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2011);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2011);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2012);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2012);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2013);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2013);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2014);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2014);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifa2015);
                md = MediaPlayer.create(Fifa1Activity2.this, R.raw.fifa2015);
                md.start();
            }
        });


        btn16.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                md.stop();
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                finish();
            }
        });


        btn17.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Fifa1Activity2.this, about_us.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2000"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2001"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2002"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2003"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2004" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2005" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2006" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2007" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2008" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2009" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2010" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2011" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2012" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2013" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2014" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIFA2015" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="دربــــاره مــا" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="خــــــــــــروج" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:paddingTop="20dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you can do

- Make sure you release your media player whenever you're done using it using `release()`
- Make sure you stop your media player whenever you're done using it using `stop()`
- Call `player.prepare()` before `player.start()`

Take a look at the life cycle to understand the methods better as well:

[image]